# c++ using "*" operator no operator matches these operands

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have in my class simple operator overloading

```
class Vec2
{
public:
    Vec2(float x1,float y1)
    {
       x = x1;
       y = y1;
    }
    float x;
    float y;
};

class FOO {
private:
    friend Vec2 operator*(const Vec2 &point1, const Vec2 &point2)
    {
            return Vec2(point1.x * point2.x, point1.y * point2.y);
    }

    Vec2 mul(Vec2 p);
};

Vec2 FOO::mul(Vec2 p)
{
    Vec2 point = p * Vec2(1,-1);
    return point;
}
```

But this multiplication gives me this error:

> `operator*`  no operator matches these operands

The problem is i can't change the Vec2 class , so i need global operator overloading

Comment: Why are you overloading `*` for `Vec2`'s, inside `class FOO` ?

Comment: i want to use the * operator inside FOO

Comment: what does it means ? where to write it ? in the header ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator*` definition should not be inside `class FOO`. Put it outside of any class definition:

```
inline Vec2 operator*(const Vec2 &point1, const Vec2 &point2)
{
    return Vec2(point1.x * point2.x, point1.y * point2.y);
}
```

You need the `inline` keyword if this is in a header file.  Then you can use the operator from within `FOO` and anywhere else.

It's not possible to restrict the operator to be usable only from within `FOO` methods. Function visibility doesn't work that way. The closest you could do would be to only have the `operator*` overload declared in some `.cpp` file that also has the point of usage, and mark it as `static` or anonymous namespace.

Comment: Do you *really* need `inline` if the function is in a header file? I always thought that functions defined in a header are implicitly inlined.

Comment: @Rakete1111 the compiler makes no distinction "header file" , after preprocessing each unit is one big file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense.

1. You don't need to define the `operator*` function inside `FOO`.
2. You don't need to make that function a `friend` of `FOO` since the function does not even use `FOO`.

Simplify your code.

```
class Vec2
{
   public:
      Vec2(float x1 ,float y1)
      {
         x = x1;
         y = y1;
      }
      float x;
      float y;

};

// This does not need to be defined inside FOO.
Vec2 operator*(const Vec2 &point1, const Vec2 &point2)
{
   return Vec2(point1.x * point2.x, point1.y * point2.y);
}

class FOO {
   private:
      // No need for the friend declaration.
      Vec2 mul(Vec2 p);
};    

Vec2 FOO::mul(Vec2 p)
{    
   // Works fine without the friend declaration.
   Vec2 point = p * Vec2(1,-1);
   return point;
}
```